# How to do unit tests in Scilab?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, scilab

I am used to do unit tests in Racket, an example would be:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

(check-equal? (add1 1) (* 2 1))
```

How can I do simple unit tests in Scilab?

I just want to have a test able to compare my expectation and another value.

https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/test_run.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison is done using *assert_xxxxx()* functions, see [help](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/assert_overview.html) for more information.

For example:

```
    a = 10;
    assert_checkequal(a, 10);

    b = 11; 
    assert_checkequal(b, 10);
     !--error 10000 
    assert_checkequal: Assertion failed: expected = 10 while computed = 11 (mean diff = 1)
    at line      22 of function assert_generror called by :  
    at line     150 of function assert_checkequal called by :  
    b = 11; assert_checkequal(b, 10);
```

As the second assert is failing, an error is risen.

In addition, you could create ".tst" files for your unit tests, in which you add your asserts. This type of files can be executed using *test_run()* function.

For example, if you create the following structure:

```
root
 - module_1
    - function_1.sci
    - function_2.sci 
 - module_2
    - function_3.sci
 - tests
    - simple_test_1.tst
    - simple_test_2.tst
```

You could execute all your unit tests by calling *test_run('tests')* from you root directory. In this case you are saying to the function the path of your unit tests, more information in [link](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/test_run.html) that you have already published.